# How to find if a field is an enum array using reflection?

Tags: java, arrays, reflection, enums

I want to find out in Java, using reflection, if a particular field is an array of enums. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I can tell if it's a enum constant, not sure if that's the same thing...

Answer (score 5):

First check if the field is an array with `field.getType().isArray()`, and then check that the array component type is an enum with `field.getType().getComponentType().isEnum()`

Answer (score 3):

As Holger mentioned in his comment a simple `Enum[].class.isAssignableFrom` will do it.

```
import javax.swing.SortOrder;

public class Main {

    private SortOrder[] sortOrders;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SecurityException,
            NoSuchFieldException {
        Field sortOrdersField = Main.class.getDeclaredField("sortOrders");

        System.out.println(isEnumArray(sortOrdersField));
    }

    private static boolean isEnumArray(Field field) {
        Class<?> type = field.getType();
        return Enum[].class.isAssignableFrom(type);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to use `isAssignable` a simple `Enum[].class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())` will do. Otherwise, why not use `return type.isArray() && type.getComponentType().isEnum();`?